# The scrollTo() function is not working as it should

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to implement a simple animation on my webpage, and I am using the `scrollTo()` function to do so. However, the button does not react.
Here is what my code:

```
<button class = "logobutton" onclick = "scroll()">
    <figure class = "icon">
        <img src = "logo.png">
    </figure>
</button>

<script>
function scroll() {
    $("body").scrollTo("#bottom");
}
</script>
```

`bottom` is the ID of my next div.

I figured that the problem could be in the fact that I am loading a wrong CDN, although I am not certain as it is the first time I am using `scrollTo()` and am new to web programming in general.

Here is the head of my doc:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.scrollto/2.1.0/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You have a typo. `onlclick` should be `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

be careful `onclick` is not spelt `onlclick` simple and easy error to make but view your code before you post it on here.

your code should be

```
<button class = "logobutton" onclick = "scroll()">
        <figure class = "icon">
            <img src = "logo.png">
        </figure>
    </button>

<script>
function scroll() {
    $("body").scrollTo("#bottom");
}
</script>
```